# How is the energy per electron in Sommerfeld Theory interpreted?

Tags: solid-state-physics, electrons, semiconductor-physics

I'm having a hard time understanding the way the energy per electron is calculated in Sommerfeld Theory. From the N.W.Ashcroft book on solid state physics it is done by first calculating the ground-state energy of N electrons in a volume V by adding up the energies of all the one-electron levels inside the Fermi Sphere : $E=2\sum_{k< k_{F}}\frac{\hbar^{2}}{2m}k^{2}$

Then we can find the energy density of the electron gas by dividing by the volume and doing some calculations but what I have trouble with is that we can then find the Energy per electron, E/N, in the ground state by dividing by N/V :
$\frac{E}{N}=\frac{3}{10}\frac{h^{2}k_{F}^{2}}{m}=\frac{3}{5}\mathcal{E}_{F}$

So my questions concern the fact that I don't understand why this energy per electron is correct, for it to be correct I think that all electrons need to have the same energy, but from $E=\frac{\hbar^{2}}{2m}k^{2}$ we can see that depending on the k and thus on the electron we have different energies.

Why is that we can simply put the same energy to each electron ? Did i misunderstand the way we interpret this energy ?

Comment: Yes, it is an average energy. Just like $3/2$ kT is the 'energy' of a monatomic ideal gas atom.